# Hide Tablix based on Report Parameters

Tags: sql, rdlc

I am working on RDLCs in SQL Server and I have many Tablix in reports.

I want to hide/show my Tablix based on my parameters.

Say I have Param1 which is a boolean (i.e either True or False)

I have written my expression as :

```
IIF(len(Parameters!Param1.Value)="True",true,false)
```

but it is not working. Please let me know what mistake I am doing.

So what expression should I write in the Tablix Visibility Option? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

len function is obsolete, just use Iif:

```
Iif(Parameters!Param1.Value = "True", true, false)
```

You don't actually need Iif, you can also just use:

```
Parameters!Value = "True"
```

Just keep in mind that if the statement evaluates to true, the tablix will be hidden - false will show it.